# Error in implementing 4 different types of users (login and signup)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am using mean stack and im implementing an application that allows 4 different types of users to interface with the app.
I implemented the first user (field agent) and the signup and login works fine.
But when implementing the second user the sign up works but the login doesnt.

After implementing all 4, only the last user (community, moc) login works.

The error received is:

> POST http://localhost:3000/authenticate 404 (Not Found)
> and
> "message": "Email is not registered"

The controller for first user is:

```
exports.authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  // call for passport authentication
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    // error from passport middleware
    if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);
    // registered user
    else if (user) return res.status(200).json({ token: user.generateJwt() });
    // unknown user or wrong password
    else return res.status(404).json(info);
  })(req, res);
};

exports.userProfile = (req, res, next) => {
  fieldAgents.findOne({ _id: req._id }, (err, user) => {
    if (!user)
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ status: false, message: "User record not found." });
    else
      return res
        .status(200)
        .json({ status: true, user: _.pick(user, ["firstName", "lastName", "employeeID", "email"]) });
  });
};
```

Route for first user:

```
router.post('/authenticate', FieldAgentController.authenticate);
router.get('/userProfile',jwtHelper.verifyJwtToken, FieldAgentController.userProfile);
```

The 4th user controller (whos login is the only one that works) is:

```
exports.authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  // call for passport authentication
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    // error from passport middleware
    if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);
    // registered user
    else if (user) return res.status(200).json({ token: user.generateJwt() });
    // unknown user or wrong password
    else return res.status(404).json(info);
  })(req, res);
};

exports.userProfile = (req, res, next) => {
  memberOfCommunities.findOne({ _id: req._id }, (err, user) => {
    if (!user)
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ status: false, message: "User record not found." });
    else
      return res
        .status(200)
        .json({ status: true, user: _.pick(user, ["username", "email"]) });
  });
};
```

Route for 4th user:

```
router.post('/authenticateMOC', MOCcontroller.authenticate);
router.get('/userProfileMOC',jwtHelper.verifyJwtToken, MOCcontroller.userProfile);
```

The passport config file:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var FieldAgents = require('./db/models/FieldAgents.model');
var DisasterManagers = require('./db/models/DisasterManagers.model');
var Administrators = require('./db/models/Administrators.model');
var MOC = require('./db/models/MembersOfCommunities.model');


passport.use(
    new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' },
        (username, password, done) => {
            FieldAgents.findOne({ email: username },
                (err, fieldAgents) => {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // unknown FieldAgents
                    else if (!fieldAgents)
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' });
                    // wrong password
                    else if (!fieldAgents.verifyPassword(password))
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                    // authentication succeeded
                    else
                        return done(null, fieldAgents);
                });
        })
);

passport.use(
    new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' },
        (username, password, done) => {
            DisasterManagers.findOne({ email: username },
                (err, disasterManagers) => {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // unknown FieldAgents
                    else if (!disasterManagers)
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' });
                    // wrong password
                    else if (!disasterManagers.verifyPassword(password))
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                    // authentication succeeded
                    else
                        return done(null, disasterManagers);
                });
        })
);


passport.use(
    new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' },
        (username, password, done) => {
            Administrators.findOne({ email: username },
                (err, administrators) => {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // unknown FieldAgents
                    else if (!administrators)
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' });
                    // wrong password
                    else if (!administrators.verifyPassword(password))
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                    // authentication succeeded
                    else
                        return done(null, administrators);
                });
        })
);

passport.use(
    new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' },
        (username, password, done) => {
            MOC.findOne({ email: username },
                (err, moc) => {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // unknown FieldAgents
                    else if (!moc)
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' });
                    // wrong password
                    else if (!moc.verifyPassword(password))
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                    // authentication succeeded
                    else
                        return done(null, moc);
                });
        })
);
```

the error message shows from the passport config file.
Essentially it all would work separately but when combined it doesnt.
Also if one of the methods in the passport config file is cut and pasted below it'll work but the 3 before it wouldnt.

Answer (score 0):

I was basically calling the same function which was overriding the previous,
it should have had different names in the passport config functions, like so:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var FieldAgents = require('./db/models/FieldAgents.model');
var DisasterManagers = require('./db/models/DisasterManagers.model');
var Administrators = require('./db/models/Administrators.model');
var MOC = require('./db/models/MembersOfCommunities.model');


passport.use( 'fieldAgent',
    new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' },
        (username, password, done) => {
            FieldAgents.findOne({ email: username },
                (err, fieldAgents) => {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // unknown FieldAgents
                    else if (!fieldAgents)
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' });
                    // wrong password
                    else if (!fieldAgents.verifyPassword(password))
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                    // authentication succeeded
                    else
                        return done(null, fieldAgents);
                });
        })
);

passport.use( 'disasterManager',
    new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' },
        (username, password, done) => {
            DisasterManagers.findOne({ email: username },
                (err, disasterManagers) => {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // unknown FieldAgents
                    else if (!disasterManagers)
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' });
                    // wrong password
                    else if (!disasterManagers.verifyPassword(password))
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                    // authentication succeeded
                    else
                        return done(null, disasterManagers);
                });
        })
);


passport.use( 'admin',
    new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' },
        (username, password, done) => {
            Administrators.findOne({ email: username },
                (err, administrators) => {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // unknown FieldAgents
                    else if (!administrators)
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' });
                    // wrong password
                    else if (!administrators.verifyPassword(password))
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                    // authentication succeeded
                    else
                        return done(null, administrators);
                });
        })
);

passport.use( 'mocUser',
    new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' },
        (username, password, done) => {
            MOC.findOne({ email: username },
                (err, moc) => {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // unknown FieldAgents
                    else if (!moc)
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' });
                    // wrong password
                    else if (!moc.verifyPassword(password))
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                    // authentication succeeded
                    else
                        return done(null, moc);
                });
        })
);
```

And these names should be associated with its designated athenticate function like so:

```
exports.authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  // call for passport authentication
  passport.authenticate("fieldAgent", (err, user, info) => {
    // error from passport middleware
    if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);
    // registered user
    else if (user) return res.status(200).json({ token: user.generateJwt() });
    // unknown user or wrong password
    else return res.status(404).json(info);
  })(req, res);
};
```